# AES шифрование, вектор инициализации

Tags: c#, криптография, aes

Появилась задача шифрования файлов.
Выбор пал на AES шифрование.
Нашел примерчик:
```c#

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {

            string original = "Here is some data to encrypt very dsfds ggfdg fgh gf  jgh jghjghj h jgh gh jgh!";

            string key = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
            string iv = "1234567890123456";

            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original,
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key),
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv));

            iv = "fqwertyuioplkjhg";


            // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
            string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv));

            //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
            Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
            Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;

    }
```

Почему если я указываю для расшифровки совершенно иной вектор инициализации, то перековерканы только первые 16 байт, а остальной текст в порядке?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и должно быть, вот картинка из статьи ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Режим_шифрования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) для улучшения понимания:
[image: CBC Decrypt]

При расшифровке первого блока расшифрованные данные ксорятся с IV. При расшифровке второго и последующих блоков расшифрованные данные соответствующего блока ксорятся с зашифрованными данными предыдущего. IV влияет только на расшифровку первого блока.

Comment: Я так понимаю, чтобы искажен был весь текст, необходимо использовать CFB режим? Проблема на самом деле возникла при использование Crypto++® Library в С++, используя CFB_Mode, увы, получаю такую же ситуацию - шифрован только первый блок

Comment: CFB/OFB/CTR вроде подойдут. Любой режим вы можете реализовать сами используя примитивы для шифрования/расшифровки отдельного блока.

Comment: На самом деле сказалась не слишком внятная для меня документация для библиотеки c++, задал в конструкторе явно один параметр по-умолчанию и начало шифровать как задумано. Но зато более серьезно вник в разницу алгоритмами шифрования

Comment: @Александр есть OpenSSL, который можно считать "эталоном".